# Comprobar status Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-api

Estoy trabajando con la API de Facebook, más concretamente con el web SDK.

Tengo creado un botón de inicio de sesión en el index.html que al pulsarlo te redirige a Facebook y en caso de iniciar sesión te redirige a la página principal.

Aquí mi duda, ¿cómo puedo comprobar el estado de la conexión del usuario desde esa página principal, de forma que si el usuario no está conectado la página le redirija de forma forzosa al index de nuevo?

He estado buscando en la documentación de Facebook y ninguna de las soluciones parece funcionarme.

UPDATE: Duda solucionada, el código que he utilizado finalmente ha sido el siguiente:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId : *AppID*,
            xfbml : true,
            cookie : true,
            version : 'v2.8'
        });
         FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            window.location.replace("http://localhost:8090/index.html");
        } else {
            window.location.replace("http://localhost:8090/index.html");

        }
    });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus)

Llamando a la funcion `getLoginStatus` puedes obtener lo que necesitas

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

  } else {

  }
 });
```

Donde puedes recibir :

- connected : El usuario esta logeado en facebook y autorizo la autenticacion con tu aplicación.
- not_authorized : El usuario esta logeado en facebook pero no conectado con tu aplicacion
- unknown : El usuario no esta logeado en facebook o bien, no autorizo a su aplicacion

En el link de la documentación tambien te explican que como muchas veces es necesario estar constantemente verificando este dato, se puede establecer un valor booleano de `status` en `true` cuando llamas a la funcion `FB.init`

> Para recibir la respuesta de esta llamada, debe suscribirse al evento `auth.statusChange`. El objeto de respuesta de este evento es idéntico al que se devuelve llamando a `FB.getLoginStatus` explícitamente.

Comment: He añadido el script de getLoginStatus añadiéndole en los ifs la redirección a la otra página, pero sigue sin hacer nada.

Comment: Ojo!, debes mostrar como lo agregaste, porque si lo haces asi, tienes que llamarlo cada vez que entre a la pagina

Comment: ` FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;

   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:8090/index.html");
   } else {
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:8090/index.html");

   }
  });`  Siento todos los errores que tengo tanto a la hora de redactar comentarios como de programar, pero soy muy novato aún y me cuesta

Comment: Primero te sugiero que agreges ese codigo a tu pregunta, para que los demas usuarios lo puedan ver. Segundo, puedes hacer un alert(response) ? para ver que responde la funcion??

Comment: Ya he añadido el código, cuando intento hacer alert directamente me da error la consola de js diciendo que "FB is not defined"

Comment: Mira tu codigo `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {` es ahi donde tienes FB.init, ahi agrega el codigo

Comment: Gracias, ya he conseguido hacerlo, cierro la pregunta y pongo el código en el post.